# ANTLR3, context sensitive rewrite rules

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I've written an ANTLR grammar, and am now in the process of constructing an AST from it. The problem at hand is, that different subtrees should be generated from a rule, depending on context. Googeling gave me this:

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/~admin/2008/04/11/Rewrite+rules#Rewriterules-Grammaticalcontext

But I can't get the syntax right from these example. So the question is: What is the correct syntax for using context sensitive rewrites in ANTRL3.4 (with the C-target, if this information is of any use)?

A minimal example is here, with one of my non-working trials to get it working:

```
grammar foo;

tokens {
    A;
    B;
}

start
    :   a
    |   b
    ;

a
    :   foo
    ;

b   :   foo
    ;

foo
    :
    [... a foo]: 'x' -> ^(A 'x')
    [... b foo]: 'x' -> ^(B 'x')
    ;
```

Thanks,
Jost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too clear from that wiki-entry, but most of that syntax is not valid: they're ideas of which some made it in to ANTLR, but some of them didn't (the `...` didn't).

To determine from which rule `foo` was *called*, you could add a parameter to `foo` and check that parameter in your rewrite rules:

```
grammar T;

options {
  // tested with Java, not C, but C should also work "as is"
  //language=C; 
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  A;
  B;
}

parse
 : (a | b)+ EOF!
 ;

a
 : 'a' foo[1] -> foo
 ;

b
 : 'b' foo[2] -> foo
 ;

foo[int param]
 : 'x' -> {param==1}? ^(A 'x')
       ->             ^(B 'x')
 ;

SPACE : ' ' {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

Parsing the input `"a x b x"` would result in the following AST:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so the way to go is to add that functionality "manually". Would be nice to have a special syntax for this stuff, as this seems to be a common use case. On the other hand, more syntax constructs would clutter the ANTLR-language... Anyway, thanks for your answer.